# How can I effectively save a tree structure in a database?

Tags: database, data-structures, tree

I am open to NoSQL and Relational Databases. This question has been asked a few times, but my twist is as follows.

I want to be able to quickly find and identify duplicate sub trees.

For example, if the tree is to index users files (and folders) on their hard drive, I might have something like:

```
    /   <-- root
  /      \
...        home
      /          \
   ugrad        course
    /          /    |    \
  ...        cs101 cs112 cs113
```

That might be for **User1**

I want to be able to find the `course` > `cs101`, `cs112`, `cs113` subtree across all other users.

What's an efficient way to structure this?

Comment: If the child nodes are unordered, it is sufficient to store the parent_id in each node. (except for the root, which han not parent)

Comment: How can I find similar sub trees?

Comment: The comment/answer was about storage, not retrieval ;-) . In SQL, retrieval would be something like: `find sets of duplicates (such as 'cs101') ; look if they have similar parents (such as 'course') , and find out if they all have the *same* parent(s) (such as 'course')` . But the "finding similar subtrees in a tree" question is pretty difficult in any language or data structure, IMHO.

Comment: Many ways... See this book: Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties, Second Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this would be a good job for a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). It should also be possible to create one in a database if you think you need one. To find similar subtrees, you then only need to examine the buckets with the same hash value as the one of the subtree to compare against, which should increase the speed.

Your question is not clear about whether you are also interested in equality of the (regular) *files* inside the directory structure, or just the directory *names* of the subdirectories. You may either design your *hash function* to respect them or not to. The same is true for file system attributes, such as permissions. You will probably not find an equal subtree in a different user’s home directory if equality includes permissions, as usually files in a user directory belong to that user.

There may be better approaches.